# JQuery toggle visibility of multiple divs with same classnames

Tags: jquery, visibility

I'm trying to show/hide multiple `div`s with classnames based on proximity to the anchor which triggers the JQuery. I think something is wrong with how I'm referencing the div which I want to show.

I have a Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lizfulghum/qKMH8/4/  and I'm assuming the issue is with this line: `JQuery(this).next(".full").show();`

The complete code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="teaser">
    Blah blah blah
    <a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle</a>
</div>

<div class="full">
    Full Text Goes Here
</div>

<div class="teaser">
    Blah blah blah
    <a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle</a>
</div>

<div class="full">
    Full Text 2 Goes Here
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".full").hide();
    jQuery(".toggle").click(function() {
        JQuery(".full").hide();
        JQuery(this).next(".full").show();
  });
});
```

Could anyone enlighten me on this point?

Comment: example has an error in the click callback... JQuery -> jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mistyped `jQuery` twice. Also you have to go one level up in the DOM tree before calling `.next()`:

```
//                             \/ aliases jQuery back to $
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".full").hide();
    $(".toggle").click(function() {
        $(".full").hide();
        $(this).parent().next(".full").show();
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qKMH8/6/)

I've aliased `jQuery` to `$` inside the DOM ready scope -- the first parameter of the [DOM Ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) receives the jQuery object itself. `$` is faster to type and less likely to mistype. You can safely use this syntax in WP and other `.noConflict()` scenarios as well.

Of course, if you have no other libraries taking the global `$` and you're not using a framework that puts jQuery into `noConflict` mode, you can use `$` instead of `jQuery` out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I added [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/). So the traversal would work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".full").hide();
    $(".toggle").click(function() {
        $(".full").hide();
        $(this).parent().next(".full").show();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qKMH8/5/